# Running python webservice on google compute engine

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to set up a scheduled python code on google compute. I am a beginner in cloud platform usage and having some trouble running python like I do on my local machine.

So I start the v instance and the ssh cloud shell. I then navigate to the folder where my main function is and then **nohup python main.py &** on the shell

This module is supposed to scrape the web, and then store the results in google spreadsheet using gspread package. I log off after running the above command.

After running for about 20 minutes or so, it says I have no active cloud shell associated with my login, hence it stops updating the results.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Python - 3.4, scheduler package - 'schedule'
Tried approaches: Tmux, screen (detach), nohup, edited the ssh_config to add ServerAliveInterval and so on. None of them helps in persisting background process on closing the ssh shell.